# Inner product identity using the centralizer

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $g\in SO(n)$. Let $v_1,v_2$ be orthogonal vectors. Let $gv_1=w_2$ and $gv_2=w_2$. I want to show that for $A$ in the centralizer of $SO(n)$ that $\langle A v_1,v_2\rangle=\langle A w_1,w_2\rangle$. But I think this might be true for any $A$.

> Is the following correct?

Note that
$\langle A v_1,v_2\rangle=Av_1v_2^T$.

Also

$$\begin{align}
\langle A w_1,w_2\rangle &=\langle A gv_1,gv_2\rangle \\
&=Agv_1(gv_2)^T \\
&=Agv_1v_2^Tg^T \\
&=Agg^Tv_1v_2^T \\
&=AIv_1v_2^T \\
&=Av_1v_2^T.
\end{align}$$

So they are both equal and I have not used that $A$ is in the centralizer.

Comment: [Centralizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of what subset? Or do you mean [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory))?

Comment: Additionally, $\langle A v_1, v_2 \rangle = v_1^\top A^\top v_2$.

Comment: @angryavian does this make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\langle A w_1, w_2\rangle
= w_1^\top A^\top w_2
= v_1 g^\top A^\top g v_2.$$
If $A$ commutes with $g$, then $g^\top A^\top = A^\top g^\top$, and we have
$$v_1^\top A^\top g^\top g v_2 = v_1^\top A^\top v_2 = \langle A v_1, v_2 \rangle.$$